# Como crear una consulta a dos tablas diferentes y renderizarlas en una misma vista con Node js Express

Tags: html5, nodejs, jade

Buenas tardes, me llamo Diego Castaño soy nuevo en esta comunidad y necesito un favor de alguno de ustedes.

En una vista (vConfSalida.jade) tengo dos select y necesito llenarlos de dos tablas diferentes que tengo en una base de datos, he logrado llenar uno de ellos con el código siguiente, pero para llenar el segundo select no se como crear la consulta dentro de ese mismo codigo.

```
getConfSalida: function(req,res,next){
      var config=require('.././database/config');
      var db=mysql.createConnection(config);
      db.connect();
      var sql=("SELECT * FROM tbl_conductor");
      var result=null;
      db.query(sql, function(err,rows,fields){
      result=rows;
      db.end();
      res.render('products/vConfSalida',{result: result});    
      });
},
```

por favor alguien me pueden indicar como hacerlo?

muchas gracias

Diego Castaño

Answer (score 0):

Probaste con algo así como esto?

```
getConfSalida: function(req,res,next){
  var config=require('.././database/config');
  var db=mysql.createConnection(config);
  db.connect();
  var sql=("SELECT * FROM tbl_conductor");
  var sql2=("SELECT * FROM tabla");
  var result=null, result2=null;
  db.query(sql, function(err,rows,fields){
    result=rows;
    db.query(sql2, function(err, rows, fields) {
       result2=rows
    })
    db.end();
    res.render('products/vConfSalida',{result: result, result2: result2});    
  });
},
```